# Compiling C file on Solaris with OpenSSL includes

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, solaris, solaris-10

I am trying to compile a C file I have written that has the include `#include <openssl/evp.h>` on Solaris 10.  The system OpenSSL files (including evp.h) are located under `/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl`, but I can't get them picked up running the following command:

```
gcc -O2 -fPIC -shared -static-libgcc -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/solaris -m64 -lcrypto -lm -std=c99 -o libencrypt64.so encrypt.c
```

I've tried adding the path to the headers to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PATH` but still get the same errors:

```
encrypt.c:54:25: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
```

... and the associated type's not found errors.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: The OS-provided OpenSSL files are located under `/usr/sfw` - anything under `/usr/local` is a local addition made at your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen $JAVA_HOME explicitly put in a gcc command before.  What is the value of $JAVA_HOME supposed to be?

Can you try adding the necessary path directly to the gcc command?  Just add

`-I/usr/local/ssl/include`

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` variable just points to the system JDK to get the JNI headers (I'm a Java developer, not very seasoned in C).  Anyway, your answer did the trick (along with removing the -m64 flag).  Thanks a lot!